# 32-bit application links with System32 binaries instead of SysWOW64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a 32-bit dll which links against (my) binaries from `System32` instead of `SysWOW64`. This dll is a `C++` project part of an *x86 `Outlook add-in`* and it should link to some binaries in the system folder, but as I'm on a *64-bit system*, I'd expect it to try and find them in `SysWOW64`, not `System32`.

I have tried copying the 32-bit version of those binaries in `System32` and that works, but it's clearly not the solution and all kind of other errors spring from it.

Where can I change the location `Visual Studio` has for the x86 system folder?

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit app running under WOW64 sees a virtualised environment, not the real filesystem.

It only thinks it is linking with System32. What it sees as System32 is in reality SysWOW64.

In a similar way it has a virtualised view of the registry and other vital system resources.

This is because the purpose of WOW64 is to enable binary compatibility. Therefore the environment the application sees must look as if it is running on a 32bit operating system.

Comment: The app is Outlook.exe x86, which loads some other binaries as an add-in. I see what you're saying, but binary compatibility is not enabled in my case. Just explaining what happened does make the problem go away so your answer doesn't really help. I already knew that: "This dll is a C++ project part of an x86 Outlook add-in and it should link to some binaries in the system folder, but as I'm on a 64-bit system, I'd expect it to try and find them in SysWOW64, not System32".

Comment: " but binary compatibility is not enabled in my case" how do you know this?  It's an emulation layer and can only be turned off for a few API calls.

Comment: because I overwrote the System32 64-bit binaries with 32-bit ones and my app linked fine with them. But that's not a solution, it's just a test. The solution would be to find out where things got messy in first place and the app tried linking in System32 instead of SysWOW64...

Comment: Your actual question "Where can I change the location Visual Studio has for the x86 system folder?" makes no sense (you cannot do that and it does not make sense to do). You need to remove your binaries from System32 and put them where they go, which is in the same folder as the Outlook Add-In, or the same folder as Outlook. They shouldn't be in System32 or SysWOW64 at all.

Comment: They're supposed to be there as my app isn't the only one using them. My question is not the main question because I don't exactly where the problem lies. Having all the binaries in the same place isn't the right thing here because deployment would involve having duplicates.

Comment: Why don't you give us some more information then. What is the DLL? Is it a publicly available library, or one of yours? What does it do? Why would it be a problem to have duplicates?